# How to make invisiable some item from select

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have Reporter model, and when I create News model, I have to choose reporter for this news, and I want to disappear Jimmy Olson from choose, but he must be in db, but not in choose list. how to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just override `get_form` method in your admin.py

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(NewsAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['reporter'].queryset = form.base_fields['reporter'].queryset.filter(name='Jimmy Olson')
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use tabularinlne of django in admin in order to ease of inserting in news model

```
class NewsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = News
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = True

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class ReporterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['race', ....]
    list_filter = ['race',....]
    inlines = [NewsInline, ]
```

> and then register your model in admin

```
admin.site.register(Reporter, ReporterAdmin)
```